# What's the origin of "qu" in the word "masquerade"?

Tags: etymology

I've noticed that the word *masquerade* is spelt with *qu* instead of *c* in *mascarade* like in French or *mascarada* in Spanish. According to Online Etymology Dictionary, the word is of French origin.

I'd be very interested to know how it came to be spelt with *qu* instead of *c* or *k* like in *mask*.

Comment: Perhaps _quay_ ("key") has a similar origin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The word is derived from Middle French *masque* (Middle French covers a period of around 1340–1610) which accounts for the *-qu-* spelling.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=masque) has

> **masque (n.)**
>       "masquerade, masked ball," 1510s, from Middle French *masque;* see ***mask*** (n.), with which it was originally identical. It developed a special sense of "amateur theatrical performance" (1560s) in Elizabethan times, when such entertainments (originally performed in masks) were popular among the nobility.

The word as imported into English hasn't changed; it appears that it has changed in French, possibly under the influence of Spanish.

Comment: Interestingly, the word 'mask' looks like the word 'maskhara' in Arabic which means a mockery.

Comment: Mask: of uncertain origin, perhaps from Arabic maskharah "buffoon, mockery," from sakhira "be mocked, ridiculed." Or via Provençal mascarar, Catalan mascarar, Old French mascurer "to black (the face)." Online Etymology Dictionary

Comment: OED doesn't have that, although it's possible that the French/Romance lanuages were influenced by the Arabic during the 13th century. However, the English *-qu-* spelling comes from Middle French attested c1590 as *-que-* and earlier as *-qua-*.

Comment: The current French word for mask is still very much spelled _masque_ (this answer does not contradict that, but I just wanted to remark this).